# Apache spark case with multiple when clauses on different columns

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

Given the below structure:

```
val df = Seq("Color", "Shape", "Range","Size").map(Tuple1.apply).toDF("color")

val df1 = df.withColumn("Success", when($"color"<=> "white", "Diamond").otherwise(0))
```

I want to write one more WHEN condition at above where size > 10 and Shape column 
value is Rhombus then "Diamond" value should be inserted to the column else 0. I tried like below but it's failing

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("Success", when($"color" <=> "white", "Diamond").otherwise(0)).when($"size">10)
```

Please suggest me with only dataframe option with scala. Spark-SQL with sqlContext is not helpful idea for me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

You can chain the `when` similar to the example in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#when-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.Object-
available since (1.4.0)

```
// Scala:
people.select(when(people("gender") === "male", 0)
 .when(people("gender") === "female", 1)
 .otherwise(2))
```

Your example:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("Success",
  when($"color" <=> "white", "Diamond")
  .when($"size" > 10 && $"shape" === "Rhombus", "Diamond")
  .otherwise(0))
```

Comment: In the example, how can I set an alias for the generated column (from when statement)?

Comment: @skdhfgeq2134 Above "Success" is the new column name where value from `when` lands

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make an UDF? 
Try something like that:

```
// Define the UDF
val isDiamond= udf((color: String, shape: String, size : String) => {
  if (color == "white" && shape == "Rhombus" && size > 10) "Diamond"
  else ""
})
val df2 = df.withColumn("Success", isDiamond($"color", $"shape", $"size"))
```

Regards.

Comment: -1 to this answer. AFAIK, you should always avoid using a UDF for any task that can be solved by chaining existing statements from the Structured API, no matter how long or complex your code looks like. The reason is that Spark's Catalyst optimizer will heavily improve your code when it is based on the Structured API, but it is blind when it finds a UDF, which is like a non-optimizable black box for Spark.