# PySpark: how to handle "else" in if chain in dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have PySpark code that pigeonholes conditions in a dataframe thus (this is a simplification to create a Minimal Working Example):

```
return df.select(
    ((df.x[0] == 0) & (df.x[1] == 0)).alias("HR_%s" % label),
    (((df.x[0] == 0) & (df.x[1] > 0)) |
    ((df.x[1] == 0) & (df.x[0] > 0))).alias("HET_%s" % label),
```

I understand what this code does, but I need to add something to catch an exception, for example, when df.x only has 1 element and df.x[1] isn't defined (for example), all conditions will fail, but how can I do that in PySpark?

Comment: is this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349830/apache-spark-case-with-multiple-when-clauses-on-different-columns" what you need?

Comment: @RemisHaroon this is close to what I wanted, but not exact, thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an "else" condition without true "error" (i.e. exception) handling, then take a look at [pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise).

If you want try "error" (i.e. exception) handling, then you will need to wrap that `try ... catch` logic as a [user-defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf).

Comment: thank you! I find it very useful to write something like `.otherwise(sys.exit('exception message here'))`

Comment: @con I recommend raising an error instead of using `sys.exit`, since `sys.exit` will override a lot of built-in safety mechanisms in pyspark. Also, make sure you wrap it as a lambda/UDF, otherwise that line will be executed at Python-interpretation-time rather than Spark-execution-time.